# SQL Count part of strings

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to count unique countries out of a column that contains addresses including streets, zip codes and so on. They are delimited by semicolons with the country at second place, like this:

```
FirstName LastName; Country; Restofaddress
```

I tried pulling the column apart and remove the parts of the column I don't need and then count the unique countries, but I cannot combine the queries into one again. What would a single query for this look like?

Comment: Share your effort, some sample data and expected results

Comment: What DBMS you are using?

Comment: @RasanjanaN question is tagged `mariadb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract the country part of the string, and then `COUNT DISTINCT` values of that:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, ';', 2), ';', -1))
FROM test
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a99ffbac1b07889eca7fe0d8a2ed48ae)

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the number of unique countries:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR (description, '[^;]+', 1, 2)) as unique_country_count
FROM address;
```

Note: This query is assuming that your table name is called address and the column is called description.

Sample Data:

```
description
----------------------------------------
FirstName LastName; USA; Restofaddress
FirstName LastName; USA; Restofaddress
FirstName LastName; China; Restofaddress
```

The unique countries are USA and China, so count is 2.

Result:

```
unique_country_count
--------------------
2
```